# "User.count" didn't change by 1 - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What `"User.count" didn't change by 1` means and how to fix it? Below is command line from console.

Here are the failures that I've got from `bundle exec rake test` and I'm looking for a way to fix them:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
 Run options: --seed 210

 # Running:

 .....F...F..

 Finished in 1.084264s, 11.0674 runs/s, 13.8343 assertions/s.

   1) Failure:
 UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user  [app/test/control
 lers/users_controller_test.rb:20]:
 "User.count" didn't change by 1.
 Expected: 3
   Actual: 2


   2) Failure:
 UsersControllerTest#test_should_update_user [app/test/control
 lers/users_controller_test.rb:39]:
 Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

 12 runs, 15 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

And addition, what does `"Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>"` mean?

And code below is what I've run in this test:

Below is line 39 in `users_controller_test.rb`

```
  37   test "should update user" do
  38     patch :update, id: @user, user: { first_name: @user.first_name, last_name: @user.last_name, email: @user.email, }
  39     assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
  40   end
```

And here is code in controller.
For 1), below is line 20 in *users_controller_test.rb*

```
  19   test "should create user" do
  20     assert_difference('User.count') do
  21       post :create, user: { first_name: @user.first_name, last_name: @user.last_name, email: @user.email, }
  22     end
```

Below is what my `users_controller#update` looks like

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**Pre Conditions:**

I've added email valuable later I've created my initial user model by following Jonathan MacDonald's YouTube tutorial "How to install Ruby on Rails on Windows 7 - Part 4, Ruby on Rails"
Process starting at 11:00

```
$ rails generate scaffold user first_name:string last_name:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

And then after playing around in console's sandbox a bit, I've added email value in my user model by following process in *6.3.1 A hashed password* from railstutorial org's e-book:

**Original command:**

```
$ rails generate migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string
My command to add email value in my user model:
$ rails generate migration add_email_to_users email:string
$ rake db:migarate
```

and then I've update following files:

***Controllers***

1) *'myapp'/app/controllers/users_controller.rb*
 [add :email in permit()]

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
end
```

2) *'myapp/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb'*
 [add email: @user.email in 'test "should create user" do' and 'test "should update user" do']

```
test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, user: { first_name: @user.first_name, last_name: @user.last_name, email: @user.email, }
end
# ...
test "should update user" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { first_name: @user.first_name, last_name: @user.last_name, email: @user.email, }
    assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
end
```

***Models***

1) *'myapp'/app/models/user.rb*
 [add validaates for email by add this line]

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
```

2) *'myapp'/test/modles/user_test.rb*
 [add email value in definition of user setup]

```
def setup
    @user = User.new(first_name: "Example", last_name:"User", email: "aaaa@bbbbbbb.com")
end

 [add email validation tasks]

    test "email should be present" do
        @user.email = "     "
        assert_not @user.valid?
    end
    test "email should not be too long" do
        @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
        assert_not @user.valid?
    end
```

***Views***

1) *'myapp'/app/views/users/_form.html.erb*
 [add field for email]

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
```

2) *'myapp'/app/views/users/index.html.erb*
 [add email coulmn in table]

```
<td>
    <%= user.email %>
</td>
```

3) *'myapp'/app/views/users/show.html.erb*
 [add email section in paragraphs]

```
<p>
    <strong>email:</strong>
    <%= @user.email %>
</p>
```

And then when I running `bundle exec rake test`, I've been facing with these error that I asked.

There is a file called `users.yml` and I didn't think this is relevant at the beginning. But it was actually been caused for these failures. So I refer code in this file in my answer. I do not refer it here in my question section for sake of simplicity.

Comment: You haven't shown us the controller code which would be causing these failures.  Suffice to say, the assumptions laid out in the test are not being brought to fruition by the actual controller, but it's tough to infer why without seeing the controller itself.

Comment: Check  log/test.log file

Comment: Can you please give us all the relevant code of your user tests - this includes the code that sets up the `@user` variable (in your tests, not the controller)? Also show us your user model (so we know what validations there are). The most likely problem is that you are failing a validation for some reason, so the user is not being created... but for us to verify that we need to know what info you are using, and what validations are expected.

Comment: Just for info, this question [has been raised on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297706/using-so-as-a-chatboard?cb=1), where the Stack Overflow community discusses how the site itself should operate. You are welcome to join the conversation there if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your heads up. It's quite useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These failures have been caused by the email attribute missing in *'myapp/test/fixtures/users.yml'* while the email attribute was added in the production environment later. I created the initial user model with `'first_name'` and `'last_name'` without `'email'`, as I described in the steps in my question.

There are many commands that help to add attributes in related files for newly added attribute after its initial creation. But I've added attributes in related files manually as you can see in below code.

*'myapp/test/fixtures/users.yml'*

**Original:**

```
one:
  first_name: MyString
  last_name: MyString
two:
  first_name: MyString
  last_name: MyString
```

**Update:**

```
one:
  first_name: MyString
  last_name: MyString
  email: MyString
two:
  first_name: MyString
  last_name: MyString
  email: MyString
```

Then run

```
$ bundle exec rake test
  Run options: --seed 1540

  # Running:

  ...............

  Finished in 2.383035s, 6.2945 runs/s, 8.8123 assertions/s.

  15 runs, 21 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

However, I've summarized meanings of '1' and '200' in list down below.

**[What dose '1' meant]**
To understand what this number `'1'` meant, you need to read next couple lines

```
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2
```

It says expected 3 but actually 2. There is only 2 attribute `'first_name'` and `'last_name'` in *'myapp/test/fixtures/users.yml'* at the begging while it suppose to have 3 attribute which is `'first_name'`, `'last_name'` and `'email'` then I'm guessing this message mentioned about number of missing attribute in *'myapp/test/fixtures/users.yml'* by pulling up number `'1'`..

**[Answer for '200']**
I thought this number has also has unique meanings that related source code instead of HTTP status code. It actually just HTTP status code. The code `'200'` means just OK as you can see in link down below.

> **10.2.1 200 OK**
>
> The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response
>   is dependent on the method used in the request...

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

It says expected response to be redirect instead of just went thorough.

Answer (score 8):

The failure to increase the User.count and the render <200> is for the same reason... you can't create the record because you failed validation.

In this test...

```
  19   test "should create user" do
  20     assert_difference('User.count') do
  21       post :create, user: { first_name: @user.first_name, last_name: @user.last_name, email: @user.email, }
  22     end
```

You're referencing @user but unless you have a setup in that test there's no @user object defined.

Try specifying values...

```
  19   test "should create user" do
  20     assert_difference('User.count') do
  21       post :create, user: { first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'johnsmith@example.com' }
  22     end
```

Comment: Hi SteveTurczyn,

Thanks for your idea. Now test works fine w/o these validation failures. But for the note, when I specifying values with actual values also works as well as specifying these strings.

Cheers!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I happy to see another great solution from you again. I trust your judgement. Thanks. It worked like charm.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn makes sense what you have said, but why does Rails setup the tests in this manner for a Scaffold model?

Comment: You can also pass a lambda like `assert_difference(-> { User.count }) do ...`

Answer (score 2):

This likely means that the controller is returning an error. You can probably see the error by dumping the content of `assigns(:user).errors`. [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) or another REPL would be helpful. Otherwise, `puts assigns(:user).errors.inspect` should work.

Comment: The above is a fantastic command (the puts one). What kind of class does assigns return that has an "errors" method? Also how do you figure out the classes and methods in Rails?

Comment: `assigns(:user)` simply returns a class variable (`@user`) in the controller. In this particular case, `@user` was assigned to be an instance of an ActiveRecord object. ActiveRecord pulls in an instance of ActiveModel::Errors and makes it available via the `#errors` method.

Comment: @will_in_wi can I do the inspections from inside PRY?  I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing it wrong or just chasing up the wrong tree

Comment: Yes, you should be able to inspect from inside pry.

Answer (score -1):

1. User should have been created, but it was not. Lots of possible reasons, i.e. duplicate email.
2. Your test expects a redirect after editing a user, but rails just renders some page. Do You have a `redirect_to @user` in `users_controller#update`?