# Another Location.count" didn't change by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, postgis

Location is basically an address with other information fields. This is my first app and I followed Hartl and others in building it, but ignored failing tests that I couldn't fix at the time. Now I'm trying to rectify that. I've looked at all the postings I found with this problem, but still can't figure it out (discussed at end). The app works, I can create new locations, so I think the error is with the test.

```
FAIL["test_should_create_location", LocationsControllerTest, 2017-02-28 12:02:08 -0800]
test_should_create_location#LocationsControllerTest (1488312128.31s)
       "Location.count" didn't change by 1.
       Expected: 4
         Actual: 3
       test/controllers/locations_controller_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:LocationsControllerTest>'
```

Edited `location_controller_test.rb` (The location controller test has 8 tests, this is the one that fails):
    require 'test_helper'

```
class LocationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @location = locations(:one)
  end

  test "should create location" do
    assert_difference('Location.count') do
      post :create, location: { address: @location.address,
                                 city: @location.city,
                                  state: @location.state,
                                   longitude: @location.longitude,
                                    latitude: @location.latitude,
                                     geom: @location.geom,
                                      coords_not_locked: @location.coords_not_locked,
                                       geocoded_with: @location.geocoded_with,
                                        extant: @location.extant,
                                         current_description: @location.current_description,
                                          source: @location.source,
                                           ref_link: @location.ref_link,
                                            notes: @location.notes }
                                            # debugger
    end

    assert_redirected_to location_path(assigns(:location))
  end
```

locations_controller.rb:
    class LocationsController < ApplicationController
      helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
      before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    # For sortable columns
    @locations = Location.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @location= Location.new({:address=> "Use W E etc and St without PERIODS"})
    repopulateResidResto()
  end

  def edit   
  end

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters (notes here from Lynda>Skoglund)
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
    # Save the object 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @location}
      else
        # If save fails, redisplay the form with information user filled in
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    repopulateResidResto()
  end # end create

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.update(location_params)
        # If update succeeds, redirect to the show page
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @location }
      else
        # If update fails, redisplay the edit form for fixing
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    repopulateResidResto()
  end # End update

  def destroy
    location = @location.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to locations_url, notice: "Location '#{location}' was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
    repopulateResidResto()
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_location
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:address, :city, :state, :longitude, :latitude, :geom, :coords_not_locked, :geocoded_with, :extant, :current_description, :source, :ref_link, :notes)
    end

    def sort_column
      Location.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "address"
    end

    def sort_direction
      %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
    end

end
```

`locations.yml`:

```
one:
  address: 1 Address1
  city: Los Angeles
  state: California
  longitude: 99.99
  latitude: 99.99
  extant: false
  current_description: MyString2
  notes: Notes1
  source: Source1
  geocoded_with: geocoded_with_1
  coords_not_locked: false
  ref_link: ref_link_1
  geom: 0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140

two:
  address: 2 Address2
  city: Los Angeles
  state: California
  longitude: 9.99
  latitude: 9.99
  extant: true
  current_description: MyString
  notes: MyString
  source: MyString
  geocoded_with: MyString
  coords_not_locked: true
  ref_link: MyString
  geom: 0101000020E61000007B4963B48E8F5DC0467C2766BD064140

three:
  address: 3 Address3
  city: Los Angeles
  state: California
  longitude: 9.99
  latitude: 9.99
  extant: true
  current_description: MyString
  notes: MyString3
  source: MyString3
  geocoded_with: MyString3
  coords_not_locked: true
  ref_link: MyString3
  geom: 0101000020E61000007B4963B48E8F5DC0467C2766BD064140
```

The model, `location.rb`:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :people, through: :years 
  has_many :resto_resid_lines


  def longlat
    "#{longitude} #{latitude}"
  end

  def notes_plus_geocode
    if notes == ""
      "#{geocoded_with}"
    else
      "#{notes} #{geocoded_with}"
    end
  end

  def full_address
    full_address = "#{address}, #{city}, #{state}"
  end

  # For next and previous in show. 
  def next
    Location.where(["id > ?", id]).first
  end

  def previous
    Location.where(["id < ?", id]).last
  end

  geocoded_by :full_address 
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :coords_not_locked?
  validates :address, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true

end
```

`test_helper.rb`

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

If I turn the debugger on in the test, `@location` is

```
(byebug) pp @location
#<Location:0x007ff26ffa1ba8
 id: 980190962,
 address: "MyString21",
 city: "MyString23",
 state: "MyString25",
 longitude: #<BigDecimal:7ff26ff96b40,'0.9999E2',18(27)>,
 latitude: #<BigDecimal:7ff26ff96a50,'0.9999E2',18(27)>,
 extant: false,
 current_description: "MyString2",
 notes: "MyString24",
 created_at: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 18:46:12 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 18:46:12 UTC +00:00,
 geom: "0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140",
 source: "MyString",
 geocoded_with: "MyString",
 coords_not_locked: false,
 ref_link: "MyString">
#<Location id: 980190962, address: "MyString21", city: "MyString23", state: "MyString25", longitude: #<BigDecimal:7ff26ff96b40,'0.9999E2',18(27)>, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7ff26ff96a50,'0.9999E2',18(27)>, extant: false, current_description: "MyString2", notes: "MyString24", created_at: "2017-03-05 18:46:12", updated_at: "2017-03-05 18:46:12", geom: "0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140", source: "MyString", geocoded_with: "MyString", coords_not_locked: false, ref_link: "MyString"
```

I'm not sure what to expect for this.

One posting that seemed relevant ["User.count" didn't change by 1 - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990576/user-count-didnt-change-by-1-rails) had incomplete yml—I've triple checked mine, but maybe still missing something.

@ArtOfCode. Creating in console (I think this is what you're asking). And since `id` is `nil` and it doesn't appear in the database, you may be on the right track:

```
    irb(main):004:0> location = Location.create( address: "1 Address1", city: "Los Angeles", state: "California", longitude: 99.99, latitude: 99.99, extant: false, current_description: "MyString2", notes: "MyString24", source: "MyString", geocoded_with: "MyString", coords_not_locked: false, ref_link: "MyString", geom: "0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140")
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      Location Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."address" = '1 Address1' LIMIT 1
      SQL (2.5ms)  INSERT INTO "locations" ("address", "state", "longitude", "latitude", "extant", "current_description", "notes", "source", "geocoded_with", "coords_not_locked", "ref_link", "geom", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14) RETURNING "id"  [["address", "1 Address1"], ["state", "California"], ["longitude", "99.99"], ["latitude", "99.99"], ["extant", "f"], ["current_description", "MyString2"], ["notes", "MyString24"], ["source", "MyString"], ["geocoded_with", "MyString"], ["coords_not_locked", "f"], ["ref_link", "MyString"], ["geom", "0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140"], ["created_at", "2017-03-05 20:00:28.246188"], ["updated_at", "2017-03-05 20:00:28.246188"]]
       (2.1ms)  COMMIT
    #<Location:0x007fe851a9bac8> {
                         :id => 177,
                    :address => "1 Address1",
                       :city => "Los Angeles",
                      :state => "California",
                  :longitude => 99.99,
                   :latitude => 99.99,
                     :extant => false,
        :current_description => "MyString2",
                      :notes => "MyString24",
                 :created_at => Sun, 05 Mar 2017 20:00:28 UTC +00:00,
                 :updated_at => Sun, 05 Mar 2017 20:00:28 UTC +00:00,
                       :geom => "0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140",
                     :source => "MyString",
              :geocoded_with => "MyString",
          :coords_not_locked => false,
                   :ref_link => "MyString"
    }
```

The application is incomplete, but you can see a location [here](https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/locations/27). Not currently allowing sign-ups, so obviously create can't be used. The addresses are more than 100 years old and the geo coordinates may not be generated. `geom` is created later in PostGIS.

I imagine there is a simple solution, but it alludes me. `gem 'rails' , '4.2.7'` and `ruby '2.3.1'`

Comment: Try using `assert_difference 'Location.count', 1 do ... end` and see what happens?

Comment: Same result (I had tried that before, but here is the result right now).       `FAIL["test_should_create_location", LocationsControllerTest, 2017-02-28 12:02:08 -0800]`
` test_should_create_location#LocationsControllerTest (1488312128.41s)
        "Location.count" didn't change by 1.
        Expected: 4
          Actual: 3
        test/controllers/locations_controller_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:LocationsControllerTest>'` Thanks for responding.

Comment: Have you verified that the `create` call does *actually* create a record (i.e. with the console)?

Comment: I added what happened at the end of the question. `id` is returning `nul` and the new location doesn't show up in the database which suggests you're on the right track assuming I did it right.

Comment: You've used `new` instead of `create` in your console testing, which is why it's not in the database.

Comment: Fixed, although I'll have to do my homework to understand the difference. `id` is not null.

Comment: `new` creates a *theoretical* record but doesn't commit it to the DB; you need to call `save` (or `save!`) to commit it. `create` creates *and* saves a new object, so you don't need to call `save`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137292/discussion-between-greg-and-artofcode).

Comment: i would gamble that the `else` block in `if @location.save` runs. You can put a debugger in there and check `@location.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: @maxple `["Address has already been taken"]`. I put debugger before the `if` and `@location.save` is `false`

Comment: `debugger` second line of `create` results in     @location
    #<Location id: nil, address: "1 Address1", city: "Los Angeles", state: "California", longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fd8c48b21e0,'0.9999E2',18(27)>, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fd8c48b1f38,'0.9999E2',18(27)>, extant: false, current_description: "MyString2", notes: "Notes1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, geom: "0101000020E61000008B187618938F5DC0C2189128B4064140", source: "Source1", geocoded_with: "geocoded_with_1", coords_not_locked: false, ref_link: "ref_link_1">. I have changed the `location.yml` to be more informative, so 1st item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixtures create database entries automatically.  Your location fixture `one` exists in the database.

So when you try a post to create a new location and you specify...

```
  post :create, location: { address: @location.address,
```

You are trying to create a location with an address that already exists, but

```
validates :address, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true
```

...specifies that the address must be unique, so the record you're attempting to post is not valid because it has the same address as an existing record.

Simply change the address in your `post :create` call

```
  post :create, location: { address: "1 A New Address",
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I didn't understand well enough that the fixture was being used twice. Once for creating the new entry as well as the existing. More studying needed on testing. Thanks again. I've been hammering on this for a week. But I do know more about debugging than I did before.